# Inconsistent useRef().clientHeight

Tags: javascript, reactjs, use-ref

I have a parent div card which can display one of three child divs. I want to adjust the height of the parent div to fit the exact contents of the currently-visible child div.

To do this, I create a `updateDonationCardSize` function which reads the `refs` of all three views, and depending on which one should be currently visible, sets the parent div height to match the appropriate child div height.

```
function updateDonationCardSize() { // Sets the size of the card to fit contents
    const height = stepOneContainerRef.current.clientHeight
    setDonationCardSize(prevState => ({
        ...prevState,
        ['width']: paymentFooterRef.current.clientWidth,
        ['height']: height
    }))
}
```

I call this function whenever any of the refs pointing to one of the subviews updates.

```
useEffect(() => {
    updateDonationCardSize()
    setTimeout(() => updateDonationCardSize(), 700)
}, [stepOneContainerRef, stepTwoContainerRef, stepThreeContainerRef])
```

Notice the silly approach above where the function is called twice, once immediately and once after a brief delay. For some reason, the first time it runs, it returns the wrong height of `830` whereas the second time it runs, it returns the correct height of `700`.

What's even stranger is that if I print out `height` variable as well as the `stepOneContainerRef` object into the console next to each other, the `height` variable is returned as `830` while `stepOneContainerRef` object actually displays its `current.clientWidth` property as `700`...

I am completely clueless and have spent hours over this already.

**Edit** - Providing additional information

The parent div contains the following structure:

```
<div id='parent div' className='overflow-hidden'>
    <div id='parent of dynamic content'>
        <div id='containerOne' className='relative' style={stepOneContainerStyle} />
        <div id='containerTwo' className='relative' style={stepTwoContainerStyle} />
        <div id='containerThree' className='relative' style={stepThreeContainerStyle} />
    </div>
    <div id='footer' />
</div>
```

and the `stepXContainerStyle` is a dictionary which sets `position: top` and `x` to `0` if it the particular div should be currently visible, otherwise it moves it outside of the overflow region to hide it.

Comment: That's probably because the first time it runs, the height *was* `830`, then it set the height to `700`, so the other read registers the correct number. I have a feeling that if you don't use a timeout it'll give you the same results.

Comment: is there a reason you cant use fit-content in css for the parent div?

Comment: @code if I don't use settimeout, or set the second timer to anything shorter than 700 then I start getting wrong results (either the same `830` I get from the first function run or sometimes some arbitrary value such as `648`)

Comment: @GianlucaFuoco `fit-content` returns a too large height because the parent container has three child containers which have `position: relative` and `top: 0`, but  together they take up more vertical space than the parent div should have (since it's showing only one of the children at a time)

Answer (score 0):

The different heights are result of unfinished DOM mutations during the rendering of the components. To fix that change `useEffect` hook to [`useLayoutEffect`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#uselayouteffect) which fires synchronously after all DOM mutations. It will allow you to call `updateDonationCardSize` only once.

In addition, you should wrap `updateDonationCardSize` with `useCallback` for correct hook dependency specification.

```
const updateDonationCardSize = useCallback(() => { // Sets the size of the card to fit contents
    setDonationCardSize(prevState => ({
        ...prevState,
        ['width']: paymentFooterRef.current.clientWidth,
        ['height']: stepOneContainerRef.current.clientHeight
    }))
}, [paymentFooterRef, stepOneContainerRef]);

useLayoutEffect(() => {
    updateDonationCardSize()
}, [updateDonationCardSize])
```

I'd also recommand to try solve this problem with CSS rules - it looks like a CSS problem more than component rendering problem.

Comment: Thanks @Bar717 I've used this code but it still functions the same. I've provided more info on the html structure of the parent div. Is there something that I'm doing wrong?